# Another doubt in Zachor?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parshat-zachor

Many shuls read the last pasuk of Parshat Zachor twice, once with "zeicher" and once with "zecher", based on a (possibly [not so valid](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6405/11532)) doubt in how the word should be read.

The Tikkun Simanim brings another uncertainty on the side: their "default" unsourced version (which is the one I've heard most often, also followed by Koren) has אֲשֶׁר־יְהוָ֣ה אֱ֠לֹהֶיךָ, while they quote the Keter Aram Tzova as having אֲשֶׁ֣ר יְהוָֽה־אֱ֠לֹהֶיךָ (this is followed by the Ish Matzliach tikkun and Artscroll).  Of course this doesn't change the meaning, but then [neither does zeicher/zecher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73238/).

What is the source of these versions?  Has anyone recommended to read both (either instead of or in addition to zeicher/zecher)?

Comment: I actually read twice this year, once normally and once before Mincha.  I decided to do one of each, so that anyone who was there for both (myself and a few others) have definitely heard it the right way once.  And anyone who was only there for one is still yotzei, either way.

Comment: I have also been doing that for many years, as I noticed the difference, so I would read it one way first, and the other way second, as the Shuls I lein at repeat the Passuk for Zecher/Zeicher, so why not...  Good catch, and good question!

Comment: @רבותמחשבות wait, you mean you repeated the pasuk 4 times?  Or you did one at shacharis and one at mincha, like I did?  Or you said אשר-ה' אלקיך...זֵכֶר followed by אשר ה'-אלקיך...זֶכֶר ׂ(or vice versa).  I'm not sure if the last one helps, since you're still only reading two of the four possibilities.

Comment: the last one.  I realize that I'm only covering 2/4, but I figured why not, being as they don't matter anyways.