זֵכר or זֶכר in אשרי?
All my life I've said זֵכר. But recently I noticed in the artscroll siddur and tehillim, זֶכר. I checked a bunch of other siddurim, they all had it as זֵכר. (Unlike parshat Zachor, no sidur mentions variant גירסאות, or a suggestion to repeat the verse.)
So which is it? Is there a debate? what's the debate about? Is it the same debate in parshat Zachor, and if so, why is there no common practice to repeat?

Artscroll is being inconsistent. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73236/759

There is an essay https://seforimblog.com/2012/03/summary-of-jordan-penkower-on-reading/

Some say both. I've also heard it argued that bc the trop is a munach the vowel should therefore be a tzeire

@Dude The trop doesn't affect the nikkud here.

A student of the Vilna Gaon wrote down (Ma'aseh Rav 28 and 134) that the Vilna Gaon read this word, and the parallel word in Deuteronomy 25, with six dots זֶכֶר, without commenting on all the other places in Tanakh this word appears. (At the time in Europe, some erroneous manuscripts and printings had caused a whole hubbub about how the word should be pronounced in verses in general, and in particular if Psalms 30:5 should be different from the rest. No one had ever suggested your case of Psalm 145:7 was different from the rest and its proper pronunciation should thus be the same as [at least nearly] every other instance of זכר in Tanakh, however you hold about that.)
Accordingly, if you follow the now widely accepted tradition (supported by all our oldest extant pointed manuscripts) to always read the word with five dots זֵכֶר but you feel compelled to technically not deviate from any snippet of the Vilna Gaon's incomplete recorded practice, then you might (as this rabbi and Artscroll Publishers seem to have done) make up an internally inconsistent "new tradition" (?) of having זֵכֶר everywhere except those two places. May God bless and keep such corruptions far away from us.

זֵכֶר לִיצִיאַת מִצְרָיִם - Everywhere that I've seen had tzere except for Siddur Shabtai Soffer

@YDJ Yes he got the worst of it. See my linked answer how ShS was using a truncated Radak and spread the six-dot version everywhere

I've emailed Artscroll to ask them. If I get a reply I'll post it here

The Chabad siddur has זֶכֶר, and if I recall correctly this is the minhag chabad, not just the way it’s printed.

@Yø-cRo If they have זֶכֶר almost everywhere in Tanakh, then they are consistently following how some acharonim (accidentally mistakenly) interpreted the mesora texts they had in front of them, and I have no theological problem with that: anyone can evaluate the masoretic evidence and paskin. That's not the same thing as making up a new text for tanach with no masorah. A good test case is זֵכֶר עָשָׂה לְנִפְלְאֹתָיו in Rosh Hashana Musaf. All the masorot agree that word זכר is pronounced the same as the word זכר in Ashrei. Anyone who has them different is being inconsistent.

@Chani Note artscroll tanakh prints "זֵכֶר". Go figure.
